# QML ProgressBar with image

Tags: qt, qml, qwidget

I would like to know how to use, as progress bar, an image.
Currently I use this code:
`

```
ProgressBar {
                id: pb
                value: 0
                minimumValue:  0
                maximumValue:  100
                style: ProgressBarStyle{
                    progress: Image {
                        source: "../icons/progress_full.png"
                    }

                }

            }
```

`

I would like that the "progression" reveals the image.
Some suggestions?

What I got currently it's a distorced image that streatches to fill the rectangle.

1° Edit:
I tried to follow Stephen Quan explanation doing this: I guess I lack some points on my code =(

```html
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import "."

Rectangle {
    id: rectangle1
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 600
    height: 130
    color: "#ffd1f9"

    // -----------------
    // PROPRIETA'
    // -----------------

    // Proprietà pubbliche
    property int        val: 50
    property alias      version: textVersion.text
    property alias      textColor: textVersion.color

    // Proprietà private
    QtObject {
        id:     d
        property int        firstColumn: 0
        property int        lastColumn: 260
    }

    // -----------------
    // WIDGET
    // -----------------

    CFBrandConst {
        id: brand
    }

    // Progressbar grafica
    Item {
        id: item1
        x: 170
        width: 271
        height: 120
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        Image {
            id: imgEmpty
            cache: (Component.status == Component.Ready)
            x: 0
            y: -56
            width: 260
            height: 91
            property real from: 0.0
            property real to: 1.0
            property real value: 0.0
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 0
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin: 0
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
            fillMode: Image.TileHorizontally
            source: "../icons/progress_empty.png"

            Image {
                id: imgFull
                cache: (Component.status == Component.Ready)
                width: (to - value) / (to - from) * parent.width//260
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.topMargin: 0
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.bottomMargin: 0
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 0
                source: "../icons/progress_full.png"
                //sourceSize: Qt.size(width, height)
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit


                onSourceChanged: {
                    onValChanged();
                }
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: textVersion
        text: qsTr("version")
        color: brand.fontColor
        font.family: brand.fontFamily
        font.pointSize: brand.fontPointSizeNormal
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        anchors.top: imgEmpty.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        }
    }


    onValChanged: {
    //SOME TENTATIVES HERE
        val = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, val));
        //imgFull.width = (100-val)/(100)*(d.lastColumn - d.firstColumn);
        //imgFull.width = d.firstColumn + (d.lastColumn + d.firstColumn) * val / 100;
        //pb.setValue(val);
        imgEmpty.value= val;


    }
}
```

Comment: For Qt5.15.x your imports should be `import QtQuick 2.15` and `import QtQuick.Controls 2.15`. For Qt6.x.x your imports will be version-less as per my answer. The error in your example is you attempting to mix version 2 controls with `import QtQuick 2.3` and version 1 controls with `import QtQuick.Controls 1.4`. You shouldn't do this. There is a lengthy explanation as to why, but, in short, you need to ensure that you `import` the latest generation of controls supported by your installation.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm forced to use QtQuick 2.3, what should I do?

Comment: But surely you can use QtQuick.Controls 2.3 as well right? Do you understand the point about not mixing version QtQuickControls 1.4 and QtQuick 2.3?

Comment: Yes I did and I corrected :)
I'm still going to try to solve my problem.
I had and image that appears as progress bar from the middle not from the left to right.
Image: |***|
The progression I would like: | -> |* -> |**...
The progression I have: * -> *** -> |***|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Image` `fillMode` property to avoid distortion. The basis comes from the following styling [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-progressbar).

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    id: root

    color: "white"
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ProgressBar {
        id: control
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        value: 0.5
        padding: 2

        background: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 200
            implicitHeight: 40
            color: "#e6e6e6"
            radius: 3
        }

        contentItem: Item {
            id: content
            implicitWidth: 200
            implicitHeight: 40

            Item {
                width: control.visualPosition * parent.width
                height: parent.height
                clip: true

                Image {
                    width: content.width
                    height: parent.height
                    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
                    source: "https://picsum.photos/300/200"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Timer {
        running: true
        repeat: true
        interval: 500
        onTriggered: control.value = (control.value + 0.02) % 1.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the `ProgressBar` definition you're using appears to be from QtQuick 1? You will find support for QtQuick 1 to be waning. I base the following on the QtQuick 2 implementation of the `ProgressBar`.

To cater for your requirements, I decided to reconstruct a `ProgressBar` by using `Rectangle` and `Image` in a creative manner.

First, let's look at the `Image` and how you're going to fit it into a `Rectangle` progress bar. I gave it some thought and, most likely your source image is square? If that's the case, consider the following code:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 50
    Image {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: backgroundImage
        sourceSize: Qt.size(height, height)
        fillMode: Image.Tile 
    }
}
```

In the above, we have the following assumptions:

1. The source backgroundImage is square, NxN pixels
2. The progress bar is rectangle, e.g. 200x50
3. We want to tile the background image in 50x50 tiles

To do that, we make use of `sourceSize: Qt.size(50,50)` which will downsample your source image to fir the progressbar based on it's height. The `fillMode: Image.Tile` which will cause the background image to be tiled neatly.

Here's a complete working example of the above implemented as `MyProgressBar` with an animation showing the progress moving from 0.0 to 1.0.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "#848895" }
    MyProgressBar {
        id: pb
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 300
        height: 50
        from: 0.0
        to: 1.0
        backgroundImage: "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/185841a46dd1440d87e6fbf464af7849/data"
    }
    NumberAnimation {
        target: pb
        property: "value"
        loops: Animation.Infinite
        running: true
        from: 0; to: 1.0
        duration: 10000
    }
}

// MyProgressBar.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 50
    property real from: 0.0
    property real to: 1.0
    property real value: 0.0
    property url backgroundImage
    border.color: "grey"
    Image {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: backgroundImage
        sourceSize: Qt.size(height, height)
        fillMode: Image.Tile 
    }
    Rectangle {
        anchors.right: parent.right
        width: (to - value) / (to - from) * parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "steelblue"
        border.color: "grey"
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Hi Stephen, I tried to follow your indications but I guess I miss something, could you help me? I edited the first post :)